# How to implement RecyclerView to Fragment of BottomNavigationBar?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I don't know how to implement ***RecyclerView*** to fragment. First I start to explain my code.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }
}
```

So `HomeFragment` should open `fragment_home.xml` which look like this...

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".NoteActivity">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView4"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="356dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="152dp"
       android:text="Home fragment"
       android:textColor="#000000"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
       tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and yes it is opening this layout ***BUT*** without ***RecyclerView*** (TextView is OK). 
I was thinking why it's happening and I came to the conclusion that I have to implement `this class` (down below) to my `HomeFragment` (or just connect that, again I don't know how)

```
public class NoteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference notebookRef = db.collection("Notebook");

    private NoteAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);

        setUpRecyclerView();
    }

    public void setUpRecyclerView() {
        Query query = notebookRef.orderBy("title", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Note>()
                .setQuery(query, Note.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new NoteAdapter(options);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Please help, thanks :)

Comment: Try logging the size of `options`

Comment: Can you explain ? I don't understand.

Comment: Use debugger put a breakpoint at `adapter = new NoteAdapter(options);` this line

Comment: Ok, I attached that and nothing happens. That class isn't already used anywhere :(

Comment: Nothing happened? Did you run the app after attaching the debugger? Nothing happened means that particular line didn't get executed.

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, or any new code you've tried, will bump it to the top of the active queue.